# localize ordinal numbers

Tags: php, localization, gettext, ordinals

for ($rank=0; $rank<100; $rank++)
    {
      printf("Your rank: %d%s", $rank, $suffix);
    }

Does there exist a gettext function to localize $suffix to the current language and return, for example:

```
Your rank: 0th
Your rank: 1st
Your rank: 2nd
Your rank: 3rd
Your rank: 4th
```

if the current locale is English, and whatever the correct "ordinal" forms of numbers are in other languages when the locale is set to something else?

Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not that I know of, but you can use [NumberFormatter](http://php.net/manual/en/class.numberformatter.php)

```
$nf = new NumberFormatter('en_US', NumberFormatter::ORDINAL);
print $nf->format(123); // prints 123rd
```

Source:

- [Internationalization in PHP 5.3](http://devzone.zend.com/article/4799)

Comment: I don't know if I've discovered a bug in PHP or the Swedish language pack, but doing this for sv_SE or sv_FI for 1 returns "1:e%digits-ordinal-neutre:0: 1:a" Or am I missing an additional argument?